# setup VueJS get data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have trouble getting data.
I get data with axios and print them with console.log, here what I have in the console :

I see my data and the lenght but I do not succeed to use them in my code. I would like for exemple to do a *for* like that :

```
for(var i; i<temp.length; i++){
        console.log(temp.name)
      }
```

This do not work since temp.lenght give 0. Or I just want to print my first argument *name: MONITOR ...* but I do not suceed either.

Do you know how we do that ?

Here the rest of my code :

```
setup() {
    const temp=[];
    onMounted(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/data/mock.json')
          .then((data) => (temp.value = data.data.data))
      console.log(temp)
      for(var i; i<temp.valueOf().length; i++){
        console.log(temp.name)
      }
    });
return{temp}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the for loop inside the `then` callback and use `ref` to init `temp` :

```js
import {ref} from 'vue'
...
setup() {
    const temp=ref([]);
    onMounted(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/data/mock.json')
          .then((data) => {
             temp.value = data.data.data
               for(var i; i<temp.value.length; i++){
                   console.log(temp.name)
                }

          })
      console.log(temp)
    
    });


   return{temp}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added temp.value[i].name in the for and now it's perfect, thank you